# Change HTML list margin with CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to reduce the margin size between sub-bullets. An example is marked below in red. How can I accomplish this using CSS?

[image: Margin change]

Comment: Can we please see your HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### It can be done by CSS:

```
ul li ul {margin-left: 10px;}
```

#### Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BUa9Z)

Comment: will this work recursively? say for example, if the sub-list had a sub-list within it?

Answer (score 1):

there are several methods do do it:

```
ul ul {margin-left: 10px;}
```

or

```
ul li ul {margin-left: 10px;}
```

or

```
ul ul li {margin-left: 10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi those are the default margins for lists, best, reset all margins then set as you wish like:

```
div, li, ul, img, body, html {margin:0px;padding:0px;}
```

after reset set as you like:

```
li {margin-left:10px;}
```

this will work for all your li elements, if nested the next list item will also be 10px away from the previous. Margin means space between an element and the next, so if you set a margin on li it will apply on every li and if nested it will look loke a stair, if thats what youre after, if you only want a margin for first level li, but not for second add this as well:

```
li li {margin:0px;}
```